# Something goes wrong with the SSH while setting up hadoop

Tags: configuration, hadoop, ssh

I'm a new fish for hadoop.I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer and I wanna install Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode on one single node.I searched and get lots of tutorials but I have a problem with the SSH.I did what the tutorial said.
I am sure the problem is about the SSH.I get the openssh-server,and had done this:
hadoop00@WebsoftStation:~$ssh-keygen -t dsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
hadoop00@WebsoftStation:~/.ssh$cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys

Then I can successfully ssh my localhost like this:
hadoop00@WebsoftStation:~$ssh localhost
It worked.
So I changed the path to hadoop and then:
hadoop00@WebsoftStation:/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo bin/start-all.sh
[sudo] password for hadoop00: 
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-WebsoftStation.out
root@localhost's password: 
root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.
So,what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have setup password-less ssh for only your current account. Since, when you can use ssh localhost without any problem, the thing you need to do next is giving execution permission to your scripts. 
Execute the following commands:

```
chmod +x bin/*.sh  ---> assigns execution permission to all the scripts
./start.all        ----> executes the script
```

Note: Hadoop can also be run without having password-less ssh setup using hadoop-daemon.sh script. The only advantage with password-less ssh is that, the ./start.all, script will take the trouble of doing that on behalf of you in each of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change permissions for your Hadoop folder to be owned by the `hadoop00` user:

```
cd /usr/local/
sudo chown -R hadoop00:hadoop00 /usr/local/hadoop
```

Then you can `cd` into the `sbin` folder and run things without `sudo`.  If you use `sudo` you're running the scripts as `root` which has different environment variables etc which is why you have a different behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `sudo` this is clearly a permission problem.

Try running this without `sudo`

```
bin/start-all.sh
```