# SSH from shellscript without password

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sh

I've generated a keypair for my school project running on a raspberry pi (running raspbian). When I run

```
ssh -f -N -R 54321:localhost:22 mylogin@host
```

in the commandline I get no problems. The tunnel is set up without me having to enter my password. However when I try to run the exact same code from a shell script it prompts me for my password. Anyone know my error?

Comment: can you share the script or how you are running the script?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657821/something-goes-wrong-with-the-ssh-while-setting-up-hadoop, Hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most Linux distributions, an instance of `ssh-agent` is started when you log in.  This is a background process that holds onto decrypted copies of your SSH keys; the `ssh` command will attempt to go through `ssh-agent` to gain access to the keys in order to do public-key authentication.  The point of `ssh-agent` is that you should only need to enter your password for an SSH key once during a login session.  (On some distros you don't even need to enter this - your keys are automatically decrypted when you log in.)

I'm guessing you're trying to run your script from cron, or from some other server process (like a web server or CGI script)?  If so, it won't have the necessary environment variables set up for the `ssh` command to talk to `ssh-agent` - so it will prompt for a password (and thus fail if it's not being run within a terminal).

You can get around this by storing an unencrypted copy of your SSH key (so you won't need `ssh-agent` to decrypt it), but as this is a major security no-no this is generally only done for SSH keys that allow access to locked-down, minimally-privileged accounts.

Comment: The keys are stored decrypted and security is no issue as it's in a classroom environment with no outside internet access. I'm launching the script from rc.local calling a python script to run the commands. When the script is called automatically i get "host key verification failed". When I manually run the script a second later everything is fine. I've found a workaround by launching xsession and running a background application but this isn't a very good solution in my opinion.